# Batch For...Do Loop script

Tags: batch-file

Please check this...

It create a folder for x number of file recursively, but the MOVE command check also on subufolder of destination_folder=Destination Folder and create a wrong number of empty folder. How to exclude destination_folder from the For...Do?
Thanks

Comment: `for /r ` is always recursively.

Comment: I know `/R` is always recursively, but the problem it is recursively also in new created subdir, so also to `"C:\My Folder\Destination Folder"` and i what to avoid/exclude that from loop or alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a check to see whether `%destination_folder%` exists within `%%~pF`.

```
FOR /R "%folder%" %%F IN (*.*) DO (

    rem --- add this ---
    set "loopfolder=%%~pF"
    if "%%~pF"=="!loopfolder:%destination_folder%=!" (
    rem ----------------

        if !n!==1 (
        etc.
```

... which basically means, after stripping the value of `%destination_folder%` from the value of the path of `%%F`, if *nothing changed*, then the path doesn't include the destination folder.  Proceed.

Comment: Please can you can be more specific? If i found `%destination_folder%` what i can do? I need to exclude that, not include. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If your loop value `%%F` contains "Destination Folder", you want to continue to the next iteration without any action, right?  That's what this does.  If the loop value `%%F` does *not* contain the text "Destination Folder", then whatever is within the `if` statement should execute.

Comment: If have test it, not work as expected. It create the correct number of folder ( example 40 files = 4 folder ) but it put all the file in the last folder, not 10 number of file in each folder. Thanks